# How to delete field using WPDB?

Tags: database, wpdb

How can I delete a field in my database under the posts table?

For example in my `posts` table where the ID is 800 I would like to delete the a field under the column `product_rank`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `product_rank` isn't a standard column in the posts table. Are you sure it's a column of the posts table and not meta?

Comment: It's a column I've created in my database. I'm able to update this column using this code however I cant figure out how I can delete fields in this column.

`$wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array('product_rank' => $rank), array('ID' => $post_id));`

Comment: @emily00p What do you mean by deleting? You can't delete a single field, however you can set it to `NULL` or similar

Comment: Can I erase the data in that field or somehow set it to NULL using WPDB? Would it be the same as updating the entry to 'NULL'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "delete" a field in MySQL, this only works for complete rows.

However, you can unset values, meaning setting them to their original state, usually `NULL` or an empty string.

```
$wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array(
    'product_rank' => NULL
), array(
    'ID' => $post_id
));
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code not working, show an error. I'm tried**

Please look at this screenshot https://prnt.sc/M3DYH_EmHCtM

```
global $wpdb;

$id = $_REQUEST['delete'];

$table = 'custom_user_info';

$wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'id' => $id ) );
```

**But when I'm using this code, It's working perfectly**

```
$db_config = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'develop');

$id = $_REQUEST['delete'];

$delete = "DELETE FROM custom_user_info WHERE id=$id";

$query = mysqli_query($db_config, $delete);
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/250999)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).